# Box shadow of "translated" box falls on sibling box

Tags: css, box-shadow

Box shadow of the box falls on the sibling box. I can use `z-index` to fix it. However, if one of the boxes is translated (e.g. move a little bit up when mouse over), the shadow falls the sibling again. How to solve this? Thanks.

```css
.container {
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.shadow {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
}

.shadow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 1000px #000;
}

.shadow:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.shadow:hover::after {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 1500px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to admit, I am not 100% clear I understand your problem. You would not like the boxshadow to display when you hover over a box?

Comment: That codepen doesn’t appear to demonstrate what you’re asking about here — it contains neither box-shadow, z-index, nor translating any element. Please include a [mcve] *in the body of the question* (not on an external site).

Comment: @JamieHutber Let's say when you hover the 2nd box from the left, then its shadow will be on the 1st box too.

Comment: @DanielBeck Updated the post

Comment: Ah, you want the shower OF the box on its friends.... I see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use translate on parent, you create a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), that places the transformed `.shadow` element on top of it's siblings. To prevent that you can use other properties than transform (`top: -3px` for example):

```css
.container {
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0;
  float: left;
  margin: 4px;
}

.shadow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 1000px #000;
}

.shadow:hover {
  top: -3px;
}

.shadow:hover::after {
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 1500px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks and it's great to know the reason behind too.